# django jquery .load object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, load

I am paginating a group of objects, each of which has a button that when pressed, opens a hidden div and pops the div in front of everything. What I want to do is list the attributes of that object in the window that pops up but I can't figure out how to fetch that object from the javascript code.

here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#create").click(function(){
            $("#popupContact").load("/cookbook/createrecipe #createform");
        });
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#popupContact").load(load object information for button1);
        });
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#popupContact").load(load object information for button2);
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% autopaginate object_list 6 %}
    <div id="object_cont">
            {% for object in object_list %}
        <div id="object">
            <div id="button{{ forloop.counter }}">      
            <h4>{{ object.name }}</h4>
            <h5>{{ object.author }}</h5>
            <h5>Prep Time: {{ object.prep_time }} minutes</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div id="popupContact" class="popup">
    <a id="popupContactClose" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;">x</a>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup">
    </div>  
    {% paginate %}
{% endblock %}
```

basically I need a way to fetch the object that is nested in the button div

thanks,
snackerfish

Answer (score 1):

First, your markup is going to result in a duplicate id parameter "object", which isn't valid HTML. However, there's no need to write individual click handlers for each button:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    /* Do whatever with content */
});
```

jQuery's load method makes a GET request. So, if you're needing to get the URL to call dynamically, I would suggest adding an anchor tag somewhere in the button div that holds the URL to load.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="object">
        <div class="button{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <a href="{% url my_view object.property %}" style="display: none;"></a>   
            <h4>{{ object.name }}</h4>
            <h5>{{ object.author }}</h5>
            <h5>Prep Time: {{ object.prep_time }} minutes</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

$('.button').click(function(){
    var content = $.load($(this).children('a:first').attr('href'));
    /* Do whatever with content */
});
```

Another thing to remember is don't use header tags where they're not needing, simply to get the presentation you want, that's what span tags, and CSS are for :)

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: this is definitely helpful. What I am missing is what the <a href="{% url my_view recipe.property %}" style="display: none;"></a> say my view is called recipe and it passes in request, cookbook.id and recipe.id. is that what the object.property is? thanks for the help

Comment: also what kind of stuff can i do with content in the js

say i wanted to get the object.name and object.author. do i do this in the js?

Comment: You would need to pass in the parameters necessary to call the view action that would return the content you need. I have no idea what properties are available on the object in your post. If object represents a cookbook, then you could pass in cookbook.id, etc. It just depends on your implementation. In your JavaScript, you can traverse the DOM to get to the properties you need as returned in the HTML from your view, or you might consider passing back JSON from the Ajax call with your content, and the other properties you need.

Comment: can you show me an example of traversing the DOM to get the properties as returned in the HTML from the view

Comment: i was also wondering if it was possible to get only a div in the piece of code **var content = $.load($(this).children('a:first').attr('href')**

Comment: Not that I'm aware of using load. You would have to load the content, then traverse it. jQuery gives you multiple ways to traverse the DOM; you can get to elements by id, css class, attribute, hierarchy, etc. Take a look at the jQuery docs to get a feel for what you can do there.